# UPS power supply for both router (12V, 2A) and up board squared (5V, 6A)

Tags: 5v, ups, sbc

I was searching for an UPS (uninterruptible power supply) to power my Up Squared Board (5V, 6A) and my router (12V, 2A).

So far I didn't find something suitable but here is my idea:

Take a suitable UPS (e.g.Mean well SCP-75-12) and convert voltage down to my needs (12V and 5V) with two dc-dc converters before feeding into the consumers. Also attach a battery of course to the UPS.

But I am a complete electronics noob so it would be great if you could help me with choosing the parts...

It doesn't necessarily have to be extremely cheap.

I want to put all the components in one small case so the dimensions should be rather small.

Also I would prefer to have components with high efficiency.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The Mean Well SPC-75-12 is NOT a UPS it is an AC to DC Converter.

Comment: Okey, let's say Mean Well DRC-60 then...

Comment: What is the efficiency of your 12 V and 5 V power supplies. As it stands you are wanting 54 W, and your UPS is rated at 59.34 W.  You also have to include the power lost in your 12 V and 5 V power supplies.